# Using columns to arrange HTML

Tags: html

First off, apologies if my title isn't the most descriptive in the world, I couldn't think of anything else for it.

I'm using a HTML5 theme by [HTML5UP](https://html5up.net/) called [Alpha](https://html5up.net/alpha). The website is intended to be a first point of help for clients using an app my colleagues have developed. I would like to make two columns, one 8 wide and one 4 wide. using bootstrap I would write this...

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    ***CONTENT***
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    ***CONTENT***
</div>
```

However this theme uses the following notation:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
        <section class="box special">
            <span class="image featured"><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></span>
            <h3>Sed lorem adipiscing</h3>
            <p>Integer volutpat ante et accumsan commophasellus sed aliquam feugiat lorem aliquet ut enim rutrum phasellus iaculis accumsan dolore magna aliquam veroeros.</p>
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><a href="#" class="button alt">Learn More</a></li>
            </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

My issue is, I've tried swapping col-sm-X straight out for Xu but that doesn't work. Can anybody here point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Ethan.

Comment: This theme doesn't use bootstrap.

Comment: Hi Germano. I know this theme doesn't use bootstrap, that is why the col-sm-X notation does not work. My question is, how can I utilise the Xu system that this theme does use? I have tried 8u and 4u as my classes but this does not work.

Comment: Why not copy the style attributes from "col-sm-4" to "6u" to override theirs?

Comment: @E.Owen ok, but why twitter-bootstrap tag?

Comment: @GermanoPlebani becasue that is something I am used to and I am looking for a translation between the two.

Comment: @RachelS I don't want to start modifying all kinds of CSS, it's just something that isn't worth the time to me.

Answer (score 2):

i try to change column width and it's working..!!

**changes:**
class="6u 12u(narrower)"  --> class="4u 12u(narrower)"
class="6u 12u(narrower)"  --> class="8u 12u(narrower)"
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Hardik. I will try that now and get back to you!

Comment: Just tried it and it still isn't working :(
The first column sizes as expected but the second one goes below not to the right of it! Thanks for your help though, you've at least helped me make _some_ progress